# How to add an element at the index using numpy in python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am new to python, Here I have an `numpy array`. Now, In this  ,

I am trying to add an element in the index in the array .

```
for x in index:
    output_result[x:x] = [300]
```

But it is not getting added, index is the position. where I want to add that element. So, can any one help mw eith this ?

Comment: you can use `np.insert` to add a value at a specific index

Answer (score 0):

are you maybe looking for something like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros(10)  # create numpy array with ten zeros
a = np.where(a == 0, 300, a)  # substitute 300 where there are zeros in array - **i assume this is what you need**

print(a)  # print generated array
print(type(a))  # print data type to show a numpy array was generated
```

or do you want to "append" a new element?

Comment: there is no reason using that loop while using np.where

Comment: you are completely right, this is from a more complex task i recently had to submit, where every element had to be filled with different - random numbers - i will edit it out. thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

With a Python list, you can insert a value with:

```
In [104]: alist = [0,1,2,3]                                                     
In [105]: alist[1:1]=[300]                                                      
In [106]: alist                                                                 
Out[106]: [0, 300, 1, 2, 3]
```

But this does not work with `ndarray`.  The array size is fixed.  The best you can do is create a new array, with original values and the new one(s).

`np.insert` is a function that can do that.  Since the operation is not particularly efficient, it's best to do a whole set of inserts at once, rather than do it iteratively.

```
In [108]: np.insert(np.arange(4),1,300)                                         
Out[108]: array([  0, 300,   1,   2,   3])
In [109]: np.insert(np.arange(4),[1,2],[300,400])                               
Out[109]: array([  0, 300,   1, 400,   2,   3])
```

(Even with a list, iterative insertion can be tricky, since each insertion changes the size of the list.  The insertion point has to take that into account (unless you iterate from the end).)